# Is there a boot option to modify key repeat behavior?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

Is it possible to specify a boot parameter to either modify the delay-until-key-repeat begins? ...or to simply turn off key-repeat entirely, like `xset r off` would do once I was logged in?

I see there is a parameter for:

```
atkbd.softrepeat= [HW]
                  Use software keyboard repeat
```

in lists of kernel parameters, but wanted to ask before just randomly booting and trying setting that `=0`. Being able to tune the repeat delay would probably be better anyway.

Comment: `xset` manipulates Xorg settings, Why you want that as kernel boot parameter, which are used only for Linux itself and its drivers? Instead I think you should configure it through `xorg.conf`

Comment: that's why I said "works like xset...", but a kernel boot option to affect the console's key repeat.

Comment: What is your underlying problem?  What are you  trying to accomplish? Do you have a bad keyboard that repeats too much and you just want to turn off key repeats?  Because the short answer is: No, there is no kernel parameter that does what you ask but there might be other ways if you describe your problem in a bit more detail.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the keyboard. Connecting through a KVM (this is a common problem if you search) and the little bit of lag from VPNs and KVM and Ubuntu 14.04 is crazy-sensitive to starting the key repeat. Can't even use the 14.04 installer. If I install directly from a local console, then the system is the same -- way to quick to start key repeat.

Answer (score 1):

For virtual consoles, there is similar tool for `xset`. You may use:

- `setterm` to turn on/off repeat

  ```
  setterm -repeat off
  setterm -repeat on
  ```
- `kbdrate` to change rate/delay

  ```
  sudo kbdrate -r <rate> -d <delay>
  ```

**References:**

- [archlinux wiki: Keyboard configuration in console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console#Temporary_configuration)
- [The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf)
- `man setterm` & `man kbdrate`

Comment: ...but my problem is that once the system boots (into an Ubuntu installer) the key repeat makes it unusable. The only chance I have is to go to expert mode in the installer boot menu, and specify some kernel arg that would adjust/disable key repeat. Then I can interact with the installer. Ultimately, I will also have to adjust the final kernel boot args to make the system usable after install.