# Root shell keyboard repeat rate

Tags: command-line, server, keyboard, root

I am not talking about the Ubuntu Desktop here, it is the "bare bones" server, pretty much any version of Ubuntu you could name, there is a very annoying keyboard "bounce" or as I refer to it "psycho uncommanded keyboard repeat." No GUI involved, just a root shell that often looks like "sudooo apttttt inssssstall" or "cd /////etc///deffffault" etc. Is there anything I can do to stop the repeat, and get the keyboard responding like it does in a remote terminal/ssh?

Comment: It seems you have a keyboard problem, nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: Thing is, every keyboard has this issue when I drop to a root shell. Pretty much every version of Debian or Ubuntu I've tried, going back to 16.04. Once a GUI loads, no problem from the same keyboard?

Comment: ssh is your friend but I still wish I could figure this problem out; ssh only works after tedious network config on the "bouncy" host

Comment: One thing I noticed: no 'bounce' when editing the grub menu. Wonder what this indicates? Looks to me like a shell always exhibits this behavior, but if I press a key a little too long while in the grub menu, I never see a keyboard issue such I posted about originally.

Comment: [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58651/adjusting-keyboard-sensitivity-in-a-command-line-terminal) has a promising possibility: 
Add `atkbd.softrepeat=1` on the kernel command line. – 
Brian Cannard
Aug 4, 2017 at 21:23

Insofar the kernel has no doubt loaded, but GUI/Deskop hasn't, this makes sense -- GRUB is pre-load of kernel, and has no bounce, root shell (from recovery mode or panic start) has loaded the kernel, and this is where I get the bounce. If this answers my Q, I'll post the solution here.

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/656564/is-there-a-boot-option-to-modify-key-repeat-behavior](This one) also looks promising, so I can tell I'm not the only one to run into it. Seems to be something to do with any non-PS2 keyboard (wireless, USB, etc.) but I've seen it also on the laptop I'm running on right now, with a hard connected keyboard! Like to find documentation on what the `atkbd.softrepeat` kernel parameter is supposed to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Although [This Link](https://lists.archive.carbon60.com/linux/kernel/621800) is a hundred years old, it led me to what looks like a working solution.

I added `atkbd.nosoftrepeat=[1]` to the kernel command line in /etc/default/grub, ran update-grub, and presto! Bounce is all gone!